# Binary heap using queue

Tags: c, data-structures, heap

There are lots of C examples by using an array to represent the tree.
However, I'm trying to use a tree(Nodes) for the Binary heap.

1. I was trying to add the child left and then right. In order to insert the elements in Width-first-Search, I've used a Queue. Is this necessary?
2. My Queue is using a Node* not a int type. Because, if I put a int in the Queue I must search the position of the Node(more time needed). Is this an appropriate way to built a Binary heap?
3. During the insertion, there are bubbling up and downs. However, since i have a binary heap and also a Queue. Do I have to match the orders in Queue also?

4.Do I need to search for inserting position like a BST? or do I approach to the address directly by using Queue?

I've learned the theory. However, the codes and structures are unfamiliar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int left(int a,int b)
{
    return (int)(a-floor((float)a/(float)b)*b);
}

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* leftNext;
    struct Node* rightNext;
}Node;

struct queue
{
    Node** data;
    int top;
    int bottom;
    int size;
}typedef Queue;

int push(Queue* Q,Node* input)
{
    printf("PUSH : %d\n",input);

    //한칸은 비울 것임.
    if(left((*Q).top-(*Q).bottom,(*Q).size)==(*Q).size-1)
    {
        printf("큐가 다 찼습니다.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        //큐의 크기를 넘으면 아래로 이동
        if((*Q).top==(*Q).size)
            (*Q).top=0;

        printf("TOP : %d\n",(*Q).top);
        (*Q).data[(*Q).top++]=input;
        return 1;
    }
}

Node* pop(Queue* Q)
{
    if(left((*Q).top-(*Q).bottom,(*Q).size)==0)
        printf("큐가 비었습니다.\n");
    else
    {
        if((*Q).bottom==(*Q).size)
            (*Q).bottom=0;

        printf("BOTTOM : %d\n",(*Q).bottom);
        return (*Q).data[(*Q).bottom];
    }
}

typedef struct Heap
{
    Node* head;
}Heap;

int insert(Node** head,int data,Queue* Q)
{
    if((*head)!=NULL)
    {
        if((*head)->leftNext==NULL)
        {
            (*head)->leftNext=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            (*head)->leftNext->data=data;
            (*head)->leftNext->leftNext=NULL;
            (*head)->leftNext->rightNext=NULL;
            push(Q,&(*head)->leftNext);
        }
        else if((*head)->rightNext==NULL)
        {
            (*head)->rightNext=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
            (*head)->rightNext->data=data;
            (*head)->rightNext->leftNext=NULL;
            (*head)->rightNext->rightNext=NULL;
            push(Q,&(*head)->rightNext);
            (*Q).bottom++;
        }
        else
        {
            if(insert((pop(Q)),data,Q)==1)
                return 1;
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("헤드가 비었습니다.");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    //입력 15 6 12 7 10 17
    Heap h;
    //큐 초기화
    Queue Q;
    //큐 크기
    int temp=100;
    Q.data=(Node**)malloc(sizeof(Node*)*temp);
    Q.size=temp;
    Q.top=0;
    Q.bottom=0;

    h.head=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    h.head->data=15;
    h.head->leftNext=NULL;
    h.head->rightNext=NULL;
    insert(&(h.head),6,&Q);
    insert(&(h.head),12,&Q);
    insert(&(h.head),7,&Q);
    insert(&(h.head),10,&Q);
    insert(&(h.head),17,&Q);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show your code (even if it is incomplete) and preferably ask one question at a time. If you just describe your code in words it is very easy to misunderstand.

Comment: @AlanAu I've inserted the codes. I was curious about the Heap Tree Data Structure itself by using Nodes. Therefore seemed it wouldn't need any codes.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. A binary heap is typically *used as* a queue, and the internal array *already is* used as a tree.